# git submodule code review with main

Tags: git, git-submodules, gerrit

I have a repo called `main` with a submodule called `sub`. What I want to do is when I make changes in `main` or `sub` for them to be a part of the same Code Review in gerrit. 
Is there any way to perform this? I can't seem to find any information to make this work.
Thanks

Comment: https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible!

> Git manages the submodule with their commit SHA id. Hence, even a sub-repo resides in a subdirectory of the main repo on your local machine, Git sees it as a submodule and doesn’t track its contents. Instead, Git sees it as a particular commit from that repository.

hence as part of the Pull-request/Code-review all you shall see on the git repo server is the changes in the commit SHA of the submodules.

Though may a git-repo-server can provide you some easy navigation to the submodule repo by providing the hyperlink to the submodule-repo-url. At least bitbucket provides the same. And after navigating to the submodule-repo, there may be another Pull-request/Code-review waiting for the reviewer.